# Retain structure as normal dataframe after transpose of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code for dataframe and transpose

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'BRAND': ['HERO','LOCAL','KEJAL','J&J'],
    'SKU': ['BIKES','MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'],
                   'JAN15 SVAL': [1,3,6,10],
                   'FEB15 SVAL': [4,5, 6,16],
                'MAR15 SVAL':[13, 14,10,12]})
dft1 = df.set_index('SKU').T
```

**Structure of dataframe:**

```
df.columns
Index(['BRAND', 'SKU', 'JAN15 SVAL', 'FEB15 SVAL', 'MAR15 SVAL'], dtype='object')
```

**Structure of transpose:**

```
dft1.columns
Index(['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'], dtype='object', name='SKU')
```

Now the difference between the structures of transpose and normal dataframe is that in transpose, the name='SKU' appears as name of dtype object. **I know I can use rename axis etc to remove the name=SKU for dtype object**, but **that doesnt change the fact that structure of df and dft1 are different**. **How can I simply retain the same structure for dft1 as the dataframe df**?

**Current transpose dataframe** 
(notice name='SKU' at the end)

```
[IN]dft1.columns
[OUT]    Index(['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'], dtype='object', name='SKU')
```

**Expected output**

```
[IN]dft1.columns
[OUT]   Index(['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'], dtype='object')
```

**Code tried:**

```
[IN] dft1
[OUT]
 SKU        BIKES   MATS BLANKETS CREAMS
BRAND       HERO  LOCAL    KEJAL    J&J
JAN15 SVAL     1      3        6     10
FEB15 SVAL     4      5        6     16
MAR15 SVAL    13     14       10     12

[IN]dft1=dft1.reset_index()
[IN]new = dft1[['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS','CREAMS']].copy() #Copying the contents of the
#transposed dataframe to see if structure same as df can be maintained where there is no name for 
#dtype object 
[IN]new.columns
[OUT]Index(['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS','CREAMS'], dtype='object', name='SKU')
```

I tried to copy the dft1 dataframe excluding the SKU column into another dataframe. I thought that if I copy few columns into another dataframe, the structure similar to df can be achieved, but still I am getting name='SKU' after dtype='object' for new.columns dataframe as well. Using reset axis can get rid of name=SKU but the structure of dft1 wont be the same still.

I am working on very very complex time series codes and it gives output only when structure is similar to a normal df. Hence **I need the structure of dft1 to be same as when you read a dataframe from a csv file for eg..**

Comment: why cant you use rename axis? an alternative is `dft1 = df.set_index(df.pop('SKU').to_numpy()).T` ?

Comment: This too doesnt retain the structure of the dataframe

Comment: how do you check structure of the dataframe? a transposed dataframe will always be different from the original dataframe